Can HAProxy support JWT validation and CORS together?
I need to support CORS between a react js application on http://localhost:3000 and an 'api gateway" proxy server(HAProxy here) on ex: http://localhost:8081.
I'm able to successfully configure CORS on HAProxy, using the latest cloned lua library at:
https://github.com/haproxytech/haproxy-lua-cors
by following the configuration in the HAProxy CORS blog post:
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/enabling-cors-in-haproxy
The preflight OPTIONS request appears to be successful.
I would also like for my HAProxy config file to support JWT validation.
I followed the configuration to validate JWT's using the HAProxy-provided syntax(without lua) by following the blog post:
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/verify-oauth-jwt-tokens-with-haproxy
I'm able to successfully decline the http requests when the JWT validation fails.  The client browser(Chrome) - receives a 403 Forbidden response from the JWT validation.  The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is not included in that 403 error response, and so the browser displays a CORS origin error:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8081' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.....
This is happening after a successful preflight OPTIONS request.
I tried to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the response - in a separate server block as directed below:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1136690/adding-custom-headers-on-error-responses-from-haproxy
The header did not come through however in the response.
Is there a way to support JWT validation and CORS together - with HAProxy?

Bear in mind that CORS-preflight requests do not carry any credentials. Make sure that JWT validation occurs +after (not before) CORS is handled.
